# Select textbox after clicking it in a checkbox type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap .
I want to focus textbox in two ways:

1. clicking the correspondent checkbox or
2. clicking the textbox

these two cases are not working.

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wr6tH/)

CSS: bootstrap-3.0.0

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" />option1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class='checkbox'>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" />
            <form role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Specify" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `form` after the `input`?

Comment: Its like other option, "if any please specify type" in a multiple choice answer

Comment: I still don't get it. I don't see the whole picture here, but as far as I'm concerned, you need just one `form` on the page, wrapping all the `inputs`, `buttons`, etc. Unless there's a very specific scenario here.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it.
Like a textbox in a checkbox?

Comment: Both are `inputs`, so no, you can't stick one inside the other.

Comment: Then I've to think of something else.
If you find a way, let me know. thanks

Answer (score 2):

IF you can add jquery here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check_1").on("change",function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#text_1").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

And your `HTML`: (added `id` attribute)

```
<div class='container'>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" />option1
    </label>
</div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" id="check_1" />
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Specify" id="text_1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wr6tH/13/